# Ignore specific java class values based on controller input

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a class:

```
@Data
public class Myclass {
    private String myString;
    private Int myint;
}
```

and a controller

```
@GetMapping
@ServicesAuditLog
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<List<MyClass>>> getMyClass(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean includeString) {
    return service.getMyClass(includeString)
        .collectList()
        .map(response -> new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

My problem is that if `includeString` is `true` and `myString` is `null`, I still want the response to have `myString = null`, so I cannot use

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Is there any way to dynamically add the `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: The short answer is "no". But you could instead return `String` from your controller and manipulate the json according to your desire.